# How can I create pipeline variables in Azure DevOps using PowerShell script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, pipeline

I already have an existing piece of script that I use to create release pipelines in Azure DevOps. I am looking to refine it to create pipeline variables that are settable at release time.

I tried adding the below to my existing script:

```
#Params section
$pipelineVariables =@{
    "Variable1" = "Value1"
    "Variable2" = "Value2"
}

#Body section
$body = @{
    "name" = $releaseName
    "variableGroups" = @($variableGroupID)
    "variables" = @(
        foreach ($varName in $pipelineVariables.Keys) {
            @{
               "name" = $varName
               "value" = $pipelineVariables[$varName]
               "isSecret" = $false
            }
        }
    )
}
```

this script is executing successfully but I do not see the variables in the "Pipeline Variables" section and also I need to figure out a way to check mark the "Settable at runtime" option.

Comment: @DanielMann, could you please look at it here?

Comment: Is this PowerShell script using the [Azure DevOps REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/?view=azure-devops-rest-7.2)? Is body intended to be the body of a request to the API? Which API are you using?

Comment: Hello @JonathanDodds, I am using Invoke-RestMethod -Uri -Method -Body -ContentType -Headers

for uri I have "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/organizationName/projectName/_apis/Release/releases?api-version=6.0" Hopefully this answers your question
I have partially added the code instead of the long one.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to invoke the [Releases - Releases - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) API. That API creates a release against an existing release pipeline (aka Definition). Are you trying to create a release or a pipeline? To create a new release pipeline you would need to invoke the [Release - Definitions - Create](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0&tabs=HTTP) API. It seems like you are mixing the two APIs.

Comment: I don't see any api method to create pipeline variables only release variables.

Answer (score 0):

We can call the release [Definitions - Update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/Definitions/Update?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0&tabs=HTTP) REST API to get the response body first, then add the variables block to the json body to create the variables.

For example, if there's already an existing variable in the release pipeline, then you can reference the following PowerShell script to create/add a new `Settable at runtime` release variable.

```
Param(
   [string]$orgurl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{org}",
   [string]$project = "0508-t",
   [string]$releaseDefid = "18",
   [string]$user = "",
   [string]$token = "PAT-Here"
)

# Base64-encodes the Personal Access Token (PAT) appropriately
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f $user,$token)))

$baseUri = "$orgurl/$project/_apis/Release/definitions/$($releaseDefid)?api-version=7.0"

$releasedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $baseUri -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} 
 
#Add a block to a json body 

$variablename = "Variable3"
$variablevalue ='{"value": "20", "allowOverride":  true}'

$releasedef.variables | Add-Member -Type NoteProperty -Name $variablename -Value (Convertfrom-Json $variablevalue) -Force

#****************** update the modified object **************************
$json = @($releasedef) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99

$updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUri -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)}

write-host "==========================================================" 

Write-host "The Variable $variablename is created."

write-host "=========================================================="
```

[image]

If no existing variables, then you have to add a new complete `variables` block including all the variables you want to be created in it. You can adjust and optimize the script based on your requirement.

Comment: Thanks @Andy Li-MSFT
I tried using the following command in my existing script and I am trying to create new variables while creating the pipeline itself.

"variables" = @(
 @{
       "NonSecretVariable1" = @{
          "allowOverride" = "true"
          "isSecret" = "false"
          "value" = "nonsecretValue"
   }
}
@{
       "NonSecretVariable1" = @{
          "allowOverride" = "true"
          "isSecret" = "false"
          "value" = "nonsecretValue"
   }
}
)
This is not working though..

Comment: @Enig Are you trying to create a release pipeline definition or just trying to queue a release (create a release from an existing release definition)? Can you please share your full PowerShell script?

Comment: Hello @Andy Li-MSFT, I am trying to create a new release definition. Let me know if this helps if not I'll share the script here.